# Eclipse 4.4 Luna ugly theme with XFCE 4.11

Tags: css, eclipse, themes, gtk3, xfce

The latest eclipse has a strange aspect in XFCE 4.11 with the Adwaita theme.
The following images show the main problems

The background of the tool-tip is white, instead of the Adwaita blue.
[image: Eclipse tool-tip with white backgroud]

The side arrows that open sub menus are plain ugly.
[image: Ugly side arrows]

Apart from this, the padding in the bars makes it very difficult to use in my laptop.
[image]

Does anyone have any suggestion?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To fix the tooltip, try to disable GTK3 by expoting `SWT_GTK3=0`. You can do this by creating a .desktop file if not already created (right click on desktop 'Create Launcher...', configure it for eclipse). Open the .desktop file with text editor and modify the line holding the execution:

> `Exec=env SWT_GTK3=0 command_to_launch_eclipse`

Comment: space-saver for eclipse mars on xfce 4.12

Answer (score 8):

Another option is to add the following lines before `--launcher.appendVmargs` in `/usr/lib/eclipse/eclipse.ini` or anywhere else where `eclipse.ini` lies:

```
--launcher.GTK_version
2
```

Source: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1546706#p1546706

Answer (score 0):

You can also run eclipse with custom theme setting, so copy your theme from /usr/share/themes/theme_name/.gtkrc to /home/user_name/.gtkrc-eclipse and run eclipse by use command

> env GTK2_RC_FILES=/usr/share/themes/your_theme/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:/home/USER/.gtkrc-eclipse '/path_to_eclipse/eclipse'

But before changes in custom .gtkrc file, you should to modify
tooltip_fg_color and tooltip_bg_color values

Answer (score 0):

It's also worth trying to change the XFCE theme. Go to Applications -> Settings -> Appearance, and try the different looks. "Adwaita" gave me trouble with the "Dark" Eclipse theme, so I switched to "Xfce-dusk" and most of the deficincies are fixed.